# selecting portion of string column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to select portion of a string column before the 'bar seperator'

'Str' column contains: `['AA|B','BB|CCC','D|LLL']`

I have already create another column named "| index"
this column returns the index number of '|' seperator

and I want to return a new column contains only substring BEFORE "|" use '.apply()' method:

```
def substring (x):
    return x[1].str.slice(0,x[2])

df['new']=df.apply(substring,axis=1)
```

However, this does not work at all !!!!
I want to know why

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Num':list(range(0,26,5)),'Str':'AA|B BB|CCC D|LLL EEE|easy f|failed g|Gg'.split()})

df["| index"] = df['Str'].str.find("|")
df

def substring (x):
    return x[1].str.slice(0,x[2])

df['new']=df.apply(substring,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                       0
0  [AA|B, BB|CCC, D|LLL]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0].tolist()).unstack().reset_index(drop=True)

##df

0      AA|B
1    BB|CCC
2     D|LLL
dtype: object

pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: [x.find('|'),x[:x.find('|')]]).tolist()).rename({0:'Bar Position',1:'Substring'},axis=1)
```

---

```
   Bar Position Substring
0             2        AA
1             2        BB
2             1         D
```